# Where am I going wrong when trying to prove $\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty }{ \frac { 1-2x }{ 3-4x } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } } $

Tags: calculus

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 1-2x }{ 3-4x } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  } $$

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$

Then, $$\left| \frac { 1-2x }{ 3-4x } -\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right| <\epsilon$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \left| \frac { 2-4x }{ 6-8x } -\frac { 3-4x }{ 6-8x }  \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \left| \frac { -1 }{ 6-8x }  \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac { 1 }{ \left| 6-8x \right|  } <\epsilon $$

Now we will calculate the lower bound on $x$ to force: $\Longleftrightarrow \left| \frac { 2-4x }{ 6-8x } -\frac { 3-4x }{ 6-8x }  \right| <\epsilon $ to hold true

Without loss of generality, assume that $x>\frac { 3 }{ 4 } $

Then, we get: $$\frac { 1 }{ 6-8x } >\epsilon$$

$$\Longrightarrow 1>\epsilon (6-8x)$$

$$\Longrightarrow 1>\epsilon 6-\epsilon 8x$$

$$\Longrightarrow \epsilon 8x>\epsilon 6-1$$

$$\Longrightarrow x>\frac { 3 }{ 4 } -\frac { 1 }{ 8 \epsilon} $$

Therefore, since $x>\frac { 3 }{ 4 } -\frac { 1 }{ 8 \epsilon} $, we can conclude that : $$\left| \frac { 1-2x }{ 3-4x } -\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right| <\epsilon \Longleftrightarrow x>\frac { 3 }{ 4 } -\frac { 1 }{ 8 \epsilon} $$

I flipped the sign after the "without loss of generality..." line because I figured that $$x>\frac { 3 }{ 4 } $$ would make $\frac { 1 }{ 6-8x } >\epsilon$ negative. I am unsure of my steps starting with the line where I put "without loss of generality..." so I need clarification as how I should proceed from there because I feel like what I did here is wrong.

Comment: If $x>\frac{3}{4}$, then $|6-8x| = 8x-6$, so you should look for the conditions needed to satisfy $\frac{1}{8x-6}<\epsilon$.

Comment: @JoeyZou So, that error threw me off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were actually at least two errors after you assumed $x > \frac 34$.

You were correct that changing $\frac{1}{\lvert 6-8x \rvert}$
to $\frac{1}{6-8x}$ is a sign change.
It is also true that you can change the signs of both sides of an inequality
if you reverse the direction of the inequality.

But that's *if you change both sides*.
What you actually did was to change the sign on the left side but *not*
on the right side. So your next inequality was not equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{\lvert 6-8x \rvert} < \epsilon.$$
An inequality that *is* equivalent, and looks a lot like what you
wrote (except for one negative sign), is
$$\frac{1}{6-8x} > -\epsilon.$$

Next, you multiplied both sides by $6 - 8x$. But remember, $6 - 8x$ is negative,
and multiplying both sides of an inequality by a negative number flips the
direction of the inequality (again), so you should have
$$1 < -(6-8x)\epsilon$$

or more simply,
$$1 < (8x - 6)\epsilon,$$
which is what you would have gotten much more easily if you had simply substituted $8x - 6$ for $\lvert 6-8x \rvert$ in the first place.